# Strange behaviour of golang UDP server

Tags: networking, udp, go

I wrote a simple UDP server in go.

When I do `go run udp.go` it prints all packages I send to it. But when running `go run udp.go > out` it stops passing `stdout` to the `out` file when the client stops.

The client is simple program that sends 10k requests. So in the file I have around 50% of sent packages. When I run the client again, the `out` file grows again until the client script finishes.

Server code:

```
package main

import (
  "net"

  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  addr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":2000")
  sock, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)

  i := 0
  for {
    i++
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    rlen, _, err := sock.ReadFromUDP(buf)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(buf[0:rlen]))
    fmt.Println(i)
    //go handlePacket(buf, rlen)
  }
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
package main

import (
  "net"

  "fmt"
)

func main() {

  num := 0
  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
      num++
      con, _ := net.Dial("udp", "127.0.0.1:2000")
      fmt.Println(num)
      buf := []byte("bla bla bla I am the packet")
      _, err := con.Write(buf)
      if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring several possible errors, both in the client and the server. When running your client, it immediately threw a runtime error. After adding an error check: "dial udp 127.0.0.1:2000: too many open files". If don't know if your problem is related, but I'd ask you to add checks for all possible errors, and if that doesn't lead to you the solution of your problem, come back here with the results :)

Comment: I added error check and have no such problems. Client works, I tested it with another server. It looks like that redirection makes lag in reading on socket, and some packets are missed....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you suspected, it seems like **UDP packet loss** due to the nature of UDP.  Because UDP is connectionless, the client doesn't care if the server is available or ready to receive data.  So if the server is busy processing, it won't be available to handle the next incoming datagram. You can check with `netstat -u` (which should include UDP packet loss info).  I ran into the same thing, in which the server (receive side) could not keep up with the packets sent.

You can try two things (the second worked for me with your example):

**Call SetReadBuffer.** Ensure the receive socket has enough buffering to handle everything you throw at it.

```
sock, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
sock.SetReadBuffer(1048576)
```

**Do all packet processing in a go routine.**  Try to increase the datagrams per second by ensuring the server isn't busy doing other work when you want it to be available to receive.  i.e. Move the processing work to a go routine, so you don't hold up ReadFromUDP().

```
//Reintroduce your go handlePacket(buf, rlen) with a count param
func handlePacket(buf []byte, rlen int, count int)
        fmt.Println(string(buf[0:rlen]))
        fmt.Println(count)
}
```

...

```
go handlePacket(buf, rlen, i)
```

*One final option:*

Lastly, and probably not what you want, you **put a sleep in your client** which would slow down the rate and would also remove the problem.  e.g.

```
buf := []byte("bla bla bla I am the packet")
time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
_, err := con.Write(buf)
```

Comment: On a side note, ReadFromUDP can be done from within go routines which can occasionally simplify processing and save a channel.

Answer (score 1):

Try syncing stdout after the write statements.

```
os.Stdout.Sync()
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. IMO stdout is flushed upon every newline it receives or the application exits normally using `exit`. See [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdout).
"The stream stdout is line-buffered when it points to a terminal. Partial lines will not appear until fflush(3)  or exit(3)  is called,  or a newline is printed."

Comment: "when it points to a terminal", the case that works is exactly that and the one that doesn't is when it isn't. Stdout doesn't get flushed at exit since the server never exits.